# PKCS#11 Signature with iText & eTPKCS11.dll & SunPKCS11 Provider

Tags: java, authentication, digital-signature, pkcs#11, sunpkcs11

I have problems when trying to make signature using SunPKCS11 Provider linked to eTPKCS11.dll. Even with iText signDetached, also when trying simple Signature, I always get "Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN".

I succesfully obtain PK, the authentication is done by callback which returns directly password for token. It seems like token needs another auth process for signature?

The device is SafeNet eToken 5110, running on Win7 64bit...

Thanks a lot!

```
public class Main {

    public static Properties properties = new Properties();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException
        {
        String userFile = "E:/plain.pdf";
        String userFile_signed = "E:/plain-tsig.pdf";

        String pkcs11Config = "name=eToken\nlibrary=C:\\Windows\\System32\\eTPKCS11.dll\nshowInfo=true";
        java.io.ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
        sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream);

        java.security.Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);
        String pin = "PIN-1234";

        KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection chp = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(new MyGuiCallbackHandler() {});
        KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", null, chp);

        KeyStore keyStore = builder.getKeyStore();
        java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
        String alias = null;
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = aliases.nextElement();
            System.out.println(alias);
        }
        System.out.println(providerPKCS11.getName());
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);


        Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
        TSAClient tsaClient = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[i];
            String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert);
            if (tsaUrl != null) {
                tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl);
                break;
            }
        }
        List<CrlClient> crlList = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();
        crlList.add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));
        Main t = new Main();
        System.out.println(providerPKCS11.getServices().toString());

        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", keyStore.getProvider());
        signer.initSign(pk);
        String data = "Hello world......";
        signer.update(data.getBytes()); 
        byte[] signedData = signer.sign();        
        System.out.println(signedData.toString());

        providerPKCS11.logout();
}

    private static abstract class MyGuiCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {

        public MyGuiCallbackHandler() {
            System.out.println("Sending PIN from callback...");
        }

        public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
            for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                String pin = "PIN-1234";
                pc.setPassword(pin.toCharArray());
            }
        }
}

}
```

And the result:

```
run:
SunPKCS11 loading ---DummyConfig-1---
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library C:\Windows\System32\eTPKCS11.dll
Information for provider SunPKCS11-eToken
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.20
  manufacturerID: SafeNet, Inc.                   
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: SafeNet eToken PKCS#11          
  libraryVersion: 10.04
All slots: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
Slots with tokens: 0
Slot info for slot 0:
  slotDescription: AKS ifdh 0                                                      
  manufacturerID: SafeNet, Inc.                   
  flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT | CKF_REMOVABLE_DEVICE | CKF_HW_SLOT
  hardwareVersion: 1.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
Token info for token in slot 0:
  label: ****               
  manufacturerID: Gemalto                         
  model: ID Prime MD     
  serialNumber: ****
  flags: CKF_RNG | CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED | CKF_USER_PIN_INITIALIZED | CKF_DUAL_CRYPTO_OPERATIONS | CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
  ulMaxSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxRwSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulRwSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxPinLen: 16
  ulMinPinLen: 4
  ulTotalPublicMemory: 32768
  ulFreePublicMemory: 25882
  ulTotalPrivateMemory: 32768
  ulFreePrivateMemory: 25882
  hardwareVersion: 16.00
  firmwareVersion: 16.01
...
PKCS#11 Provider ->SunPKCS11-eToken using library C:\Windows\System32\eTPKCS11.dll
Sending PIN from callback
sunpkcs11: login succeeded
iSignum 00000000-000000
...
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineSign(P11Signature.java:591)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1207)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:579)
    at TSTgo.Main.main(Main.java:146)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_SignFinal(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineSign(P11Signature.java:553)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: can you please tell me how you managed to get the sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 class? mine is missing... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missing login bit.

`providerPKCS11.login(null, YourCallbackHandler)`

Comment: Hello, I tryed to add this, but unfortunately got the same error :( I thought that signature method (may) call the login callback itself...

Comment: To be precise, if i call .login(null, handler) with debugging on, i got sunpkcs11: user already logged in... Maybe there must be subject specified?